# Latest post first in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**Is there any way by which I can show the latest post first in react**

I was not able to  find any way to solve this problem

```html
import React from 'react'
import firebase from '../firebase'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import News from './News'
import logo from '../logo.svg';
import '../App.css'

export default function NewsProvider() {

    const [news, setNews] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("news");

    function getNews() {
        console.log("Loading news started");
        setLoading(true);
        ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            const items = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                items.push(doc.data());
            });
        console.log("stopped");
        setNews(items);
        setLoading(false);
    });
    }
    

    useEffect(() => {
        getNews();
    }, []);

    if (loading) {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
              <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <h1>Loading</h1>
            </header>
          </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
     

    console.log(news);
    
    return (

        <div>
        <News news = {news} />
        </div>
    )
    




}
```

Is there any way by which I can show the latest post first in react

Comment: your news object will be having some date field, just sort by it.

Comment: Try changing items.push(...) to items.unshift(...)

Answer (score 0):

In getNews function add new items to the beginning of an array with **unshift**

*Be careful, unshift() overwrites the original array.*

Here is an example:

```js
const querySnapshot =["Banana","Orange","Apple","Mango","Lemon","Pineapple"];
const items = [];
 querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                items.unshift(doc);
            });
console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

just use .collection("news").orderBy("date","desc")

just make a new field in your database of dateTime

Comment: const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("news").orderBy("Date","desc");